# Special symbols appear datatable select query

Tags: c#

A special symbol "'", datatable.select method of conditional value in how to deal with? For example: datatable.select ("name='test's'");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
var filteredRows = from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                   where row.Field<string>("name") == "test's"
                   select row;
```

Then you can use `ToArray` if you want a `DataRow[]`(as `DataTable.Select` returns) or `CopyToDataTable` if you want a new `DataTable` with only the matching rows or you could simply use a `foreach` to enumerate these rows.

You can also stay with `DataTable.Select`, you need to escape the apostrophe with two:

```
datatable.Select(string.Format("name ='{0}'", "test's".Replace("'","''")));
```

Comment: name='test's'  in this expression, there is a single quotes in test's, leading to expression syntax error. How to solve this problem

Comment: Tim, I think his string is `test's` not `'test's`

Comment: yes, the value is test's, not 'test's. I try write :datatable.Select(string.Format("name ='{0}'", "test's".Replace("'","''")));but it not right

Comment: @user3292074: i've tested this code with a simple datatable with two rows and it worked. What means _it not right_?

Comment: If test's becomes test''s, not to the matching results. But not error

Comment: @user3292074 It is a double quotation mark or 2 single quotation mark? These are different.

Comment: This is the resulting filter-string: `name ='test''s'`. It works if you want to find rows where the name-field is `test's`. However, have you tried to use the LINQ approach. You won't fiddle around with `DataTable.Select` anymore.

Comment: thank you Tim Schmelter,thanks Soner Gönül!

Answer (score 2):

[`DataTable.Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses the same expression rules with [`DataColumn.Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

From documentation;

> User-Defined Values
>
> User-defined values may be used within expressions to be compared with
>   column values. String values should be enclosed within single
>   quotation marks (**and each single quotation character in a string value
>   has to be escaped by prepending it with another single quotation
>   character).**

If your string is  `test's`, first your should use another single quotes for each to escape your quotes inside your string, then you should use another quotes to enclose your string.

Like;

```
datatable.select("name = 'test''s'");
```

Also as Tim *[suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672539/447156)*, using `String.Format` method could be more clear. Like;

```
datatable.Select(string.Format("name ='{0}'", "test's".Replace("'","''")));
//Stolen from Tim's answer :)
```